# Google App Engine Error: DNS lookup failed for URL: http://metadata.google.internal

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been working on a small Google App Engine (standard environment) project that uses Cloud Endpoints v2. My code is largely based on the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python) provided by Google.

Everything was working fine, but I re-deployed today after having not looked at it for a few weeks, and I'm getting the following error when I attempt to call the endpoint:

> error: An error occured while connecting to the server: DNS lookup failed for URL: metadata.google.internal

This wasn't happening before. It seems to be happening when the endpoints package is being imported by Python.

My endpoint doesn't do anything fancy - I haven't changed the source from the sample EchoApi. The error ends up in the GCP Logging console no matter if I try to access the API through the API Explorer or via Curl.

I don't get any errors during deployment.

**Edit #1**

Some further information:

The error originates from within Google's code that is included with the `google-endpoints` package which I've included in my `lib` folder, per 
the documentation. Specifically, the error occurs on line 54 of `google/api/control/wsgi.py`.

Basically, it's making a request to `metadata.google.internal` using urllib2.

I'm guessing this address is only available from within the Google Cloud, and that for whatever reason, the instance that's hosting my app can't do a DNS lookup on it.

**Edit: #2**

Dug a bit further.

It seems that the error originates in the google-endpoints-api-management package. Changes committed to that package on October 19th seem to have introduced additional platform reporting. metadata.google.internal is queried to check if the code is running within the Google Container Engine, then it blows up, because the metadata address doesn't resolve.

Here's the commit:
https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-management-python/commit/0a37d0e443091053ed03e455e06d3a0ae770999f

The google-endpoints package only requires google-endpoints-api-management >=1.0.0b1. On my end, things were working fine on version 1.0.0b2, but then I built a new lib folder, which brought down 1.0.0b5, and things went sideways. Required packages haven't changed between b2 and b5, so I'm thinking I may be able to just downgrade back to b2 for the time being. Haven't tried it yet.

Sent the Google Dev an email. Perhaps he'll chime in with further tips.

**Edit: 2016-11-07**

Tested downgrading the google-endpoints-api-management package to 1.0.0b2. Seems to be working, kludgy a fix as it is. If you're using the lib folder, the following will scrub the newer error-prone wsgi.py file and put back the older one:

```
pip install -t lib google-endpoints-api-management==1.0.0b2 --upgrade
```

Not pretty, but it may just get you back in business.

On a side note, the Google engineer promptly replied saying that he would take a look at this issue soon. With luck, endpoints v2 will eventually come out of beta, 'cause I'm really liking it so far.

Comment: having the same issue, same example, same traceback. at first thought it was because the instance_class and basic_scaling werent set in the app.yaml, but that wasn't the issue

Comment: @dgmt Glad I'm not the only one. I spent several hours assuming that the issue was configuration related as well. I've made further discoveries, outlined in the second edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in an upcoming patch to the google-endpoints-api-management package (which will be 1.0.0b6). It will probably be released sometime on Monday, 11/6.

If you'd like to continue testing right away and this error is blocking you, you can go back to 1.0.0b4 until 1.0.0b6 comes out. Everything should still work as normal with that version.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! We're doing our best to iron out all of these wrinkles now during beta in preparation for our first general release.

EDIT: 1.0.0b6 has been released and resolves this issue. Thanks for your patience during our beta phase!

Comment: pip install -t lib google-endpoints-api-management==1.0.0b4 --extra-index-url=https://gapi-pypi.appspot.com/admin/nurpc-dev --ignore-installed
Collecting google-endpoints-api-management==1.0.0b4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-endpoints-api-management==1.0.0b4 (from versions: 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.7, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0b2, 1.0.0b5)
No matching distribution found for google-endpoints-api-management==1.0.0b4


there is no 1.0.0b4, only 1.0.0b2

Comment: apart from the lib version, this solution works for me

Comment: My pleasure, @HondaGuy!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Google has released version 1.0.0b6 of the google-endpoints-api-management package to address this issue. It solved the problem for me. For anyone who is encountering this problem, clean out your lib folder and re-install the google-endpoints package. This will bring down the new google-endpoints-api-management package with it.

Thanks to Brad at Google for really quick action on this.